# Dataframes in Python

Tags: python, list, dataframe

Hi I have a dataframe like this:

```
A             B
```

0:  some value    L1
1:  some value    L2

I want to change it to something like below

```
A             B
```

0:  some value    [[L1, L2]]

Comment: Please could you add some reproducible code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain the grouping as list with this code:

```
df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].apply(list)
```

And if you want to add a new column with the result will be the next code:

```
df['col4'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])['col3'].transform('sum').apply(list)
```

You will obtain the next output:

```
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0    id1    value1   a    [a, b, c, d]
1    id1    value1   b    [a, b, c, d]
2    id1    value1   c    [a, b, c, d]
3    id1    value1   d    [a, b, c, d]
4    id2    value2   e    [e, f]
5    id2    value2   f    [e, f]
6    id3    value3   g    [g, h]
7    id3    value3   h    [g, h]
```

Comment: Hi , I am sorry if i was bad in explaining my request. I have a dataframe as below. I have the col1,col2 and col3. I need a fourth column 'output' as below.   col1 col2 col3 output
1 value1 a [a,b,c]
1 value1 b [a,b,c]
1 value1 c [a,b,c]
2 value2 e [e,f]
2 value2 f [e,f]
3 value3 g [g,h,i]
3 value3 h [g,h,i]
3 value3 i [g,h,i]

Comment: Could you add a reproducible pandas dataframe instead of trying to explain it? Could be easier...

Comment: import pandas as pd
data = {'col1':  ['id1', 'id1', 'id1', 'id1', 'id2', 'id2', 'id3', 'id3'],
        'col2': ['value1', 'value1', 'value1', 'value1', 'value2', 'value2', 'value3', 'value3'],
        'col3': ['a', 'b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
        'col4': [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['a','b','c'],['e','f'],['e','f'],['g','h'],['g','h']]         
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
print(df)

Comment: I need help to get col4

Comment: You want to group the columns 1 and 2 and concatenate the result of the third one? But in the example you send me the third row is not taking into account. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, I need to group columns 1 and 2 and concatenate the third one as a list.

Comment: Does this solution fix your problem?

Comment: Accepting the answer is to click the tick button in the post at the top left corner of the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers